# Can I extend a class in a header file without using include?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have these three files:

Abstract class `Person` defined in a header file:

**Person.h**

```
class Person {
    public:
    char * name;
    virtual char * days_work(int count, int price) = 0;
};
```

Class `Miner` which extends `Person` defined in a header file:

**Miner.h**

```
class Miner: public Person {
    public:
    int gold_mined;
    void days_work();
};
```

And the definition of the member functions of `Miner` in a code file:

**Miner.cpp**

```
#include "Miner.h"
#include "Person.h"

Miner::Miner(char * name) {
    this->name = name;
    this->gold_mined = 0;
}
Miner::~Miner() {}
void Miner::days_work() {
    this->gold_mined += 10;
}
```

When I compile this (with gcc) I get an `invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Person’` error.  I can get it to compile by putting `#include "Person.h"` at the top of `Miner.h`, but everyone keeps telling me that including header files within other header files is bad practice.  For the most part I have been able to avoid it by using forward declarations of classes. (e.g. `class Person;` in `Miner.h`), but that doesn't work in this case.

Every question I can find on the topic suggests including the header file.  I keep seeing phrases like 'quick and dirty fix' and 'dog and bird solution', but I can't find anything better.

Is there a way to define a class extension in a header without including a header within a header?

What do you consider best practice in a situation like this?

Comment: "including header files within other header files is bad practice" Where did you read this?! It is utter nonsense.

Comment: Seriously. That's like saying 'using the + symbol for addition is bad practice'.

Comment: @0O0O0O0: right, everyone knows you must use std::plus() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/ !  ;-)

Comment: The compiler **must** know the layout of `Person` in order to compile `Miner`, since `Miner` inherits from `Person`, therefore you **must** include `Person.h`. The rest has already been stated by others.

Comment: @Biffen The next time I see everyone I'll tell them you said that.  :) Honestly, I can't remember where I heard it.

Comment: It's a bad idea to include _unnecessary_ headers, in particular those where a forward declaration would have been sufficient. But a base class must have been fully defined, and therefore you _should_ include the base class header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there a way to define a class extension in a header without including a header within a header?

Yes but painful. Don't do it.

Any time you use

```
 #include "Miner.h"
```

you also have to add

```
 #include "Person.h"
```

before that statement.

If you think about what `#include` means -- the pre-processor includes the contents of the file in the compilation unit -- it will become clear.

Replace the line

```
 #include "Miner.h"
```

with

```
class Miner: public Person {
    public:
    int gold_mined;
    void days_work();
};
```

This is not valid code since the definition of the class `Person` must be known before the above code can be compiled.

Now, replace the lines

```
 #include "Person.h"
 #include "Miner.h"
```

with

```
class Person {
    public:
    char * name;
    virtual char * days_work(int count, int price) = 0;
};

class Miner: public Person {
    public:
    int gold_mined;
    void days_work();
};
```

Now, everything should compile just fine.

You also asked:

> What do you consider best practice in a situation like this?

When defining a derived class, *always* `#include` the header file of the base class.

Answer (score 7):

> Everyone keeps telling me that including header files within other header files is bad practice

Then everyone is wrong!  Header files including other header files is absolutely the correct and normal thing to do.  And it is required in this case.

What is true is that you should not #include files which you do not actually need.  Some people tend to #include lots of headers in other headers when they are not required (either totally unused or perhaps a "forward declaration" would have sufficed, e.g. if the only need for the header is to declare a pointer to a class declared within it).

So, #include what you need, don't #include what you don't need, and "everyone" should be happy.

Comment: If I hadn't asked I would have felt bad about doing the only thing that works.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend a class `Person`, the definition of that class has to be known by the compiler.

It is true that you should try to keep the number of `#include`s to minimum (header file or not), because every new entry potentially increases the amount of code to compile. In bigger projects you can also hit the problem of circular dependencies (file A includes B, and vice versa). Where appriopriate, includes should be replaced by forward declarations.
But sometimes - such as in your case - an include is necessary.

What *is* a bad practice, is to leave an `#include` out and rely on the fact that one file is included before another in all `.cpp` files you use them in.

Answer (score -1):

Including header means you are inserting the code defined in header file(which is include) at top of that file. So  you have to be careful there should not be repeated definition.

In your example,

**#include "Person.h" at the top of Miner.h means**

```
**Miner.h**

class Person {
    public:
    char * name;
    virtual char * days_work(int count, int price) = 0;
};

class Miner: public Person {
    public:
    int gold_mined;
    void days_work();
};

It is fine.

But you add both the header in Miner.cpp

Miner.cpp
/* minor.h  start
class Person {
    public:
    char * name;
    virtual char * days_work(int count, int price) = 0;
};

class Miner: public Person {
    public:
    int gold_mined;
    void days_work();
};
*/ minor.h end

/*Person.h start
class Person {
    public:
    char * name;
    virtual char * days_work(int count, int price) = 0;
};

/*Person.h end
```

So there is duplicate definition of Person, So it should give error. So you have to be very careful when you are adding header into another header

Comment: You just need an #ifdef to protect your headers against multiple inclusions. Look at any distributed header file for an example.

Comment: @casey Not *just* an `#ifdef`, though.